# How do I create a tar or tar.gz archive entirely from objects in memory (no files) in Java

Tags: java, tar

How do I create a tar or gzipped tar archive in Java that isn't backed by `File` and actual files?

I've found [commons-compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/index.html), but the examples and most of the documentation rely on using already existing files that can be referenced by a Java `File` object. What if I don't want to use a `File` object and want to build my tar archive from `byte[]`.

The only constructors for `TarArchiveEntry` that provide a way to set the content accept `File` and there is not setter for content.

From the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveEntry.html) for TarArchiveEntry:

```
TarArchiveEntry(File file)
   Construct an entry for a file.
TarArchiveEntry(File file, String fileName)
    Construct an entry for a file.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [commons-compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/index.html), it isn't immediately clear or exemplified in the documentation, but here is the gist of it

```
//Get the content you want to lay down into a byte[]
byte content[] = "I am some simple content that should be written".getBytes();

//Name your entry with the complete path relative to the base directory
//of your archive. Any directories that don't exist (e.g. "testDir") will 
//be created for you
TarArchiveEntry textFile = new TarArchiveEntry("testDir/hello.txt");

//Make sure to set the size of the entry. If you don't you will not be able
//to write to it
textFile.setSize(content.length);


TarArchiveOutputStream gzOut = null;
try {

    /*In this case I chose to show how to lay down a gzipped archive.
      You could just as easily remove the GZIPOutputStream to lay down a plain tar.
      You also should be able to replace the FileOutputStream with 
      a ByteArrayOutputStream to lay nothing down on disk if you wanted 
      to do something else with your newly created archive
    */
    gzOut = new TarArchiveOutputStream(
                new GZIPOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("/tmp/mytest.tar.gz")
            )));

    //When you put an ArchiveEntry into the archive output stream, 
    //it sets it as the current entry
    gzOut.putArchiveEntry(textFile);

    //The write command allows you to write bytes to the current entry 
    //on the output stream, which was set by the above command.
    //It will not allow you to write any more than the size
    //that you specified when you created the archive entry above
    gzOut.write(content);

    //You must close the current entry when you are done with it. 
    //If you are appending multiple archive entries, you only need  
    //to close the last one. The putArchiveEntry automatically closes
    //the previous "current entry" if there was one
    gzOut.closeArchiveEntry();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (gzOut != null) {
        try {
            gzOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, alright. I'm still fairly inexperienced with StackOverflow.

Comment: @vmarbut in your question you specified in memory but the answer you supplied you save the tar to `"/tmp/mytest.tar.gz"`. i understand this is an old question but did you find a way to do it without saving the file as i am having issues with the 512 limit on lambda disk storage

Comment: @Lonergan6275, yes, it's in the comment of that code. Just use a different type of output stream like the ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: `//You must close the current entry when you are done with it. 
    //If you are appending multiple archive entries, you only need  
    //to close the last one. The putArchiveEntry automatically closes
    //the previous "current entry" if there was one
    gzOut.closeArchiveEntry();` this is not true, you MUST close archive entry every time, otherwise you will get an archive with corrupted data.